# Set 2 values in strpos?

Tags: php, strpos

I'm stuck on this:

I run quite a few `strpos` in my code, and all of them work with 1 value. But when I need to use 2 values, I cannot get the code working.

Here is the issue, this works with 1 value, but not 2:

```
<?php 

$a = strtolower($title); 

if (strpos($a, 'opel') !== false) { 
    echo '<h2>Why Opel?</h2>'; 
} 

?>
```

But I cannot find the right code to work with for example 'opel' 'corsa'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a conjunction?

```
<?php
  $a = strtolower($title);
  if (strpos($a, 'opel') !== false && strpos($a, 'corsa') !== false) { 
    echo '<h2>Why Opel Corsa?</h2>';
  }
?>
```

Like this?

Comment: I tried, but didnt think I had to use != false  both times. I just put it  like: 

 `if (strpos($a, 'opel') && strpos($a, 'corsa') !== false) {`

But thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Yep, done. Thanks again. With the code I mention above, I just got blank page, but with "flase" for both values it works. Thank you again!

Comment: @easyquestions True that.